# Can a node in a cluster managed by Kubernetes discover its healthy peers?

Tags: .net, kubernetes, microservices, load-balancing, peer

*(I am a kubernetes novice, and my company uses kubernetes to manage our microservice architecture. We use ASP.NET and C#)*

I have a cluster of identical service instances, which have some state and do long-running work. Each instance is always available to receive a request to the cluster, but I would like the work for the request to be handled by whichever node within the cluster which is the least-loaded. (i.e. I want the receiving node to forward the request to the most free node.)

My services provide an api to query for their current load. "Load" in my scenario is not measurable by simple cpu/memory usage, so a typical load balancer doesn't help here. However, since service instances may randomly become unhealthy, and I may scale up or down the cluster, the set of "currently healthy nodes" is dynamic and cannot be injected via config at deploy time.

**Does Kubernetes expose an api that my service could query to get back the set of instances that are healthy/available?** If so, I could easily discover my healthy nodes, and then ping them for their load, in order to decide who to forward to.

Edit: I'm particularly interested in whether there is an existing C# library I could use to do this.

Comment: Is your cluster running [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#readme)? If so, [`kubectl top nodes`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-nodes-and-cluster) (and by definition the underlying api call it makes) may get you where you want to go

Answer (score 0):

Why look for the health of the nodes when services are unhealthy? But since you are looking for Node health then Kubectl provides a node problem detector that should help with your problem. You can find more information on it from here :-

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/monitor-node-health/

Comment: I am only trying to discover the nodes that are healthy

Comment: @PeterBeissinger Did the link provided above helped? The suggestion is to create a daemonset which will perform the health check based on the config provided and write it to a file shared over some volume. It will then to us how we interpret log and create metrics out of it.

Comment: The link would probably help if I wanted to do this using raw kubectl. I was actually hoping there was a C# library to help me do this. I'll update my question to reflect this.